# I created a channel with "guild.create_text_channel" but I couldn't find how to send a message to the channel I created

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I created a channel with "guild.create_text_channel" but I couldn't find how to send a message to the channel I created. I'm using discord.py

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    messageID = <myMessageID>
    channell = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channell.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

    if messageID == payload.message_id:
        member = payload.member
        guild = member.guild
        emoji = payload.emoji.name

        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = False),
            guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
            guild.get_role(<myRoleID>): discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True)
        }

        if emoji == '✅':
            channel = guild.create_text_channel(str(member)+"-ticket", overwrites=overwrites,)
            await channel
            await message.remove_reaction('✅', member)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a message in a channel using [`TextChannel.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=textchannel#discord.TextChannel.send).

PS. [`Guild.create_text_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=create_text_channel#discord.CategoryChannel.create_text_channel) is a `coroutine` so you should `await` it.